# Java Swing JTextArea: Problem displaying Myanmar Text

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I have a problem displaying Myanmar text correctly on a JTextArea.
The correct text is

သူ အစိမ်းရောင် ဘောလုံးကို ရွေးခဲ့သည်

but in my JTextArea it is displayed as:

[wrongly displayed text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4OeO.png)

The order of some of the characters are incorrect. 
This happens when I copy the text from other programs (Chrome/MSWord) into the JTextArea.

Any help/pointers is much appreciated

Comment: which font are you using?

Comment: Does this incorrect ordering happen every time you copy Burmese characters to `JTextArea` from a non-java application? If not, does it happen when you copy only Burmese characters? Does it happen when you copy text that contains both Burmese characters and non-Burmese characters? Does the copied text contain non-printable characters, for example the [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character)?

Comment: @JarlikStepsto, I am using the Myanmar Text font.

Comment: @Abra, the incorrect ordering of the characters seems to happen for some characters only, and yes, everytime I copy from a non-java application. It happens if I copy text that contains both Burmese and non-Burmese characters too. No, the copied text does not contain any non-printable chracters.

Comment: I notice in MSWord when I move the caret from one character to another, ဘော is 1 unit or 1 character, whereas in JTextArea it consists of 2 units or 2 characters.

Comment: So if you copy ___only___ Burmese characters, the ordering is always correct, yes?

Comment: @Abra, no, copying only Burmese charactes, the ordering is incorrect.

Comment: I am using JDK10 on a Windows 10 64bit machine ...  I read here [link](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8184054 ) about a similar problem in MacOS for JDK 7 and 8 which was solved in JDK 9. Since I am using JDK10, I thought the problem should be resolved.

Comment: Thank you @Abra and Jarlik Stepsto for your response.  Managed to solve the problem, reading [link](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8223558)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve the problem by enabling ligature and kerning.

Changed my code from

```
    Font srcFont = new Font(srcFontFace, Font.PLAIN, fontSize);
    setFont(srcFont);
```

to

```
    Font srcFont = new Font(srcFontFace, Font.PLAIN, fontSize);
    Map attributes = srcFont.getAttributes();
    attributes.put(TextAttribute.LIGATURES, TextAttribute.LIGATURES_ON);
    attributes.put(TextAttribute.KERNING, TextAttribute.KERNING_ON);
    setFont(srcFont);
```